# Div's contents showing with opacity set to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to get a panel to slide up when a trigger is selected. This is working in my snippet. The issue is that the contents within the `#proposal-panel` are showing, even though I have `#proposal-panel` set to `opacity: 0`, until the trigger is clicked (`.active` is added). It is showing at the bottom of the page.

Also, for some reason on my actual site, the panel is not sliding up. I have multiple sections, just like the example. The panel just sets at the bottom of the page. The only thing that happens when the active class is added is the `z-index` takes effect.

I am wanting the panel to slide from the bottom to the top when triggered. That is what I am trying to do with `translateY`in the active class.

Does anyone know why the contents are showing and possibly why the panel is not sliding up?

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/eywLcqx2/1/)

```js
$('#proposal-trigger').on('click', function () {
  $('#proposal-panel').addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
#red {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#blue {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
#proposal-trigger {
 background: #3B3B3B;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 200px;
}
#proposal-panel {
 background: #333333;
 width: 58%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 15px 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: -100vh;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#proposal-panel.active {
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
 transform: translateY(0vh);-webkit-transform: translateY(0vh);
 bottom: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="red"></section>
<section id="blue"></section>
<div id="proposal-trigger">
  <input>
  <input>
</div>
<div id="proposal-panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's the little black box you see at the bottom, that's from `#proposal-trigger`. `#proposal-panel` is hidden. I removed the background color from `#proposal-trigger` to get rid of that.

And to have the element slide up, use `transform: translate()`.

```js
$('#proposal-trigger').on('click', function() {
  $('#proposal-panel').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#red {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#blue {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

#proposal-trigger {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 200px;
}

#proposal-panel {
  background: #333333;
  width: 58%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  bottom: 0;
}

#proposal-panel.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="red"></section>
<section id="blue"></section>
<div id="proposal-trigger">
  <input>
  <input>
</div>
<div id="proposal-panel"></div>
```

Comment: The dark gray box is essentially a button and is supposed to be there, however the inputs I am not wanting to show until the large panel `#proposal-panel` is showing.

Comment: @Paul then put the inputs in `#proposal-panel`...?

Comment: @Paul *"The issue is that the contents within the #proposal-panel are showing, even though I have #proposal-panel set to opacity: 0,"* no they aren't. You don't have any content in `#proposal-panel`

Comment: @Paul your CSS is invalid. On line 452 in the source of that page, you have a commented out block for `#proposal-panel` and an uneven number of open/close comments inside of it. Just remove that block and your CSS works. Or you can fix the inner comments if you want to keep it there.

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck on that for an embarassing amount of time. I forgot I commented out the top part. I appreciate you taking a look!

Comment: @Paul no sweat. If you use your dev tools, you'll see that `#proposal-panel` doesn't have any CSS applied to it. Yet you obviously have some CSS there for it, so the next step is to figure out why the CSS isn't being applied and it's usually because of some kind of syntax error. Glad we figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use translateY to do this animations, just need to use top and bottom with the fixed position. And remove the background-color from #proposal-trigger so it doesn't show anymore

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eywLcqx2/3/)

```
$('#proposal-trigger').on('click', function () {
    $('#proposal-panel').addClass('active');
});

<section id="red"></section>
<section id="blue"></section>
<div id="proposal-trigger">
  <input>
  <input>
</div>
<div id="proposal-panel"></div>

#red {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#blue {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
#proposal-trigger {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 200px;
}
#proposal-panel {
    background: #333333;
    width: 58%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#proposal-panel.active {
    transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 1;
}
```